# Is there a Shapeshift service for Testnet coins to convert Bitcoins to other Altcoin testnet coins?

Tags: altcoin, testnet, testing

I'm building an app and I'm working with btc testnet coins, but I want to be able to convert them to other altcoin testnet coins. Is there such a service out there?

Comment: I don't understand the point of this.  They are separate currencies, so normally the only way to "convert" them is a trade with another party, buying one currency and paying for it with the other.  But testnet coins have no value, and you can obtain them without paying anything.

Comment: Its just for the ease of getting altcoin testnet coins without having to post somewhere and wait for someone to give them to you. I was just wondering was there a quick way of doing it.

Comment: ^ Imagine you want to create a script like shapeshift.io or changelly.. how would you test it without using live coins.. There is definitely a need for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most testnet coins have a working faucet to obtain coins. Alternatively you can usually mine them with a CPU.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a service that can do that as there isn't a purpose but you can, however, is mentioned already are mine or use a faucet or ask anyone you know who has extra that you can use and after you finished with it, return or give those testnet coins away to other developers that need it.